# JavaScript getter defined as an array instead of a function?

Tags: javascript, mozilla, getter

I can't reconcile the following with any of the JavaScript documentation I've read. Can somebody please shed some light?

The following snippet is taken from [file panelUI.js in the Mozilla repository](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/components/customizableui/content/panelUI.js).

```
const PanelUI = {
  /** Panel events that we listen for. **/
  get kEvents() ["popupshowing", "popupshown", "popuphiding", "popuphidden"],

  // more properties...

  _addEventListeners: function() {
    for (let event of this.kEvents) {
      this.panel.addEventListener(event, this);
    }
    // more code...
  },

  // more properties...
```

Everything I've read about JS defines a getter as essentially a function (or "*a method that gets the value of a specific property*" and "*The get syntax binds an object property to a function that will be called when that property is looked up*"), so I'm a bit baffled to see an array literal where I would expect to find the body of function `kEvents()`.

What does it mean in JS to have a function name followed by an array literal (in general or as part of a get definition)?

How would you write code that is functionally equivalent to the above, but does not use this somehow odd syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is a consequence of SpiderMonkey's non-standard and deprecated support for [expression closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Expression_closures).

Comment: Yes, thanks, that must be it. "Expression closures are a shorthand function syntax for writing simple functions [...] This syntax allows you to leave off the braces and 'return' statement [...] There is no added benefit to writing code in this manner, other than having it be syntactically shorter." - Glad it's deprecated now!

Answer (score 1):

this isn't valid JavaScript in any way... unless Firefox is allowing it as an alternative syntax for some reason.

but if you tried to run this or similar code in a browser like chrome, or even trying to compile it using Babel and ES6, it fails.

Answer (score 0):

> How would you write code that is functionally equivalent to the above, but does not use this somehow odd syntax?

An "equivalent" syntax appears to be to wrap the data in curly braces and return it:

```
get kEvents() {
    return ["popupshowing", "popupshown", "popuphiding", "popuphidden"];
},
```

I would guess that the example code returns the same array instance every time, whereas my code is going to generate a new array every time it's called.

I imagine that the listed line is a non-standard syntax that mozilla has implemented but that is not associated with any current spec. Oftentimes with these sorts of features the browser development community pushes a browser to implement a new feature to see if it's worthwhile for standardization. It could have been a proposed syntax that was later dropped as well

That all said, this is speculative, as I've never seen a standard with that syntax in it.